# How to export a prototype method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, import, export

How to export a prototype method?

I created a prototype method:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(elementToRemove: any): void {
    var __idx = this.indexOf(elementToRemove);
    if (__idx >= 0) {
        this.splice(__idx, 1);
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Cannot find element ${elementToRemove}`)
    }
}
```

and I want to export it and use in another file. But I don't know how to add export to it:

both

```
export Array.prototype.remove = function(elementToRemove: any)
```

and

```
Array.prototype.remove = export function(elementToRemove: any)
```

doesn't work, I received 'Expression expected' Error. So how can I export it?

ps: I'm not using nodejs, I'm using web frontend in chrome with HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that your code performs a *side-effect* - it adds something to `Array.prototype`.

One option is to export a function that, when called, adds the function to the prototype:

```
export const addRemoveToPrototype = () => {
  Array.prototype.remove = function( // ...
```

and then consumers can use it by doing

```
import { addRemoveToPrototype } from './addRemoveToPrototype';
addRemoveToPrototype();
```

Another option is to simply run that code at the top level of the module:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(elementToRemove: any): void {
```

and then consumers can just import the module, but not do anything with it:

```
import './addRemoveToPrototype';
```

That said, I'd really recommend not mutating built-in objects - it makes the code fragile and more easily breakable, especially when other scripts run in the same environment.

Comment: But I received 'Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'any[]'.'  is that a problem?

Comment: You would have to indicate to TypeScript that the property exists on the prototype - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64522938 `declare global { interface Array ...` - but a much, much better approach would be not to mutate the prototype in the first place, and call a normal function to perform the logic instead.

Comment: For example, consider if you could instead do: `export const removeFromArray = (array: Array<unknown>, elementToRemove: unknown) => {` and go from there

Comment: Problem solved, Thanks! And I think I should avoid to define at prototype