# How to add a getter (extend) to the global Object or Array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add, for example a `isEmpty` getter to the `Object` or `Array`, but I'm having trouble to do so because I think I'm not really understanding how to access properties through `this`:

```js
declare global {
  interface Object {
    isEmpty: boolean;
  }
}

// 1. Doesn't work
Object.prototype.isEmpty = this.keys.length === 0;

// 2. Doesn't work either
Object.prototype.isEmpty = Object.keys(this).length === 0;
```

Is it really possible to make this work? How would it be with `Array`?

References:

- [How to properly extend Array prototype in Typescript 4.0.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64522938/4756173)
- [Bobby Hadz's *How to Extend Object.prototype in TypeScript*](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-extend-object-prototype)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10592753/2887218) more or less

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WokMlW) work for you?  If so I could write up an answer, although with big caveats about how it is almost universally discouraged to add novel functionality to native prototypes this way.

Comment: I think that is working, thank you very much! Although I'm getting this from ESLint, as expected: `Object prototype is read only, properties should not be added`. Why exactly is this kind of thing discouraged? Some languages actually encourage this sort of extension patter (e.g. Dart).

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-extend-native#rule-details `In JavaScript, you can extend any object, including builtin or “native” objects. Sometimes people change the behavior of these native objects in ways that break the assumptions made about them in other parts of the code.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ⚠ WARNING! ⚠

**IT IS WIDELY CONSIDERED BAD PRACTICE TO MODIFY NATIVE PROTOTYPES**, mainly because it might change the code — specially its behavior — other programmers depend on.

See [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/2887218) for more information.  In what follows I'm going to show how to do it, but this is not meant to say that you *should* do it.  A standalone `isEmpty()` function would work just as well, and is far less controversial.

Do check out @Dimava's answer as well, as he shows yet another way of doing this.

---

If you want to [append a getter to an existing object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#defining_a_getter_on_existing_objects_using_defineproperty), then you need to use [the `Object.defineProperty()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Your example could therefore look like:

```
// declare global { // <-- needed within modules
interface Object {
  isEmpty: boolean;
}
// }

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "isEmpty", {
  configurable: true,
  get() {
    return Object.keys(this).length === 0;
  },
});
```

As for `Array`s, you could simply do the same but with `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, ...)`.

And you can verify that it works as desired:

```
const a = { z: 1 };
console.log(a.isEmpty) // false

const b = {};
console.log(b.isEmpty) // true
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBMFMGMBsEMBOlQHNYHsBG9agN6gigA8AtGaBgHawCeoAltaALYbgCuskAzgLAAoZgBdIiAGbxoKAPJYAVjBEEhoJrwCirAA4i6ALlBYMGHvGoBuIQF8hxO4KHyl0EQDooE5pAAKiDB1xfQAKF2V3HQCRDH0ggBpQACJGLV19JMT8NVBoGm9UTkR4LB4jEUROSETUSBEQgEoCUGQRIpZwt3cAa0g6XhCRAAtUhvcealRh0ABeOdAABlBHGwbrJ0E86l4VeFnmgC8jAEZl9a2d4338G3OaXjNIcYxUEPh3VO09OibiKVheJAhBdHs9XlgPmlvr8wBUqkIhEA)

Comment: If the reason for not extending these native prototypes is changing behavior, then what I'm proposing is not a problem, I don't think. And that's simply because I'm not changing anything, I'm simply adding a derivative property that actually doesn't change the behavior under other programmers' feets.

Comment: Anyways, I'm torn apart between giving the answer to you or @Dimava, since he showed something I hadn't seen elsewhere (and he has way less points than you). Who do you think I should give it to? (Thank you very much for your answer anyways.)

Comment: Hey, don't ask me which one to accept .  I'm obviously biased toward myself: I usually try to give links to sources for my information so that it's not just my opinion.

Comment: As for adding a new property to `Object.prototype`, this is fine as long as nobody else comes along and tries to add a different `isEmpty` there.  What if another developer makes `isEmpty` a *method* so you have to call `foo.isEmpty()`?  It's far less controversial to make your own function (especially if it's module-scoped) rather than modify anything other code can access.  Again, I'm not saying you *can't* do it, or even that you necessarily *shouldn't*.  I'm just saying that it's widely considered bad practice.

Comment: I think the actual bad practice here is not having a freaking compiler that would point to developers that there are conflicting extensions to native prototypes :P 

Comment: I briefly edited your answer to include a pointer to our discussion and to Dimava's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this way it's easy to make extensions, and you don't have to worry about correct descriptors (making them non-enumerable, etc) and correct typing

```
class ObjectExtension extends Object {
    get isEmpty() {
        return Object.keys(this).length === 0;
    }
}

function extendSuperclassPrototype(classExtension: new (...a: any[]) => any): void {
    let desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(classExtension.prototype);
    delete (desc as any).constructor;
    let superproto = Object.getPrototypeOf(classExtension).prototype;
    Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, desc);
}

declare global {
    interface Object {
        isEmpty: ObjectExtension['isEmpty']
    }
}

extendSuperclassPrototype(ObjectExtension)

console.log(({a: 1}).isEmpty, ({}).isEmpty)
```